# Firestore security rules is supposed to have a values method

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

In the following documentation they reference a *value* method for the firestore security rules. I unfortunately could not get that working.

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/role-based-access

```
function getRole() {
  // Read from the "roles" map in the story document.
  return value(/databases/$(database)/documents/stories/$(story)).roles[request.auth.uid];
}
```

What I could get working is this:

```
function getRole() {
  return resource.data.roles[request.auth.uid];
}
```

So I wonder why they don't use this simpler version? And if they would want to be more explicit, shouldn't they use the *get* method instead of *value*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is old documentation from our alpha program which someone avoided our docs scrub for public beta. `resource.data` & `get()` are definitely what you want to use.

(We'll get it updated :))

Comment: Hey thanks, that's what I assumed, there was just no way to reply on the documentation. But please don't remove this page, just update. It is the only good explanation of role based access control. Only after reading this I understood how it's meant to work! Best would be of course to integrate into  the official documentation but right now it seems https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview is loosing information instead of gaining :-(

Comment: You can always click the send feedback link/button on our doc pages. For Firebase you'll see it on the top left blue bar. You can also give us feedback on the official group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-firestore-discuss

Comment: The feedback button does not seem to exist on the outdated documentation, it only shows me "contact sales" :-)

Comment: Yes, the Google Cloud website doesn't have it, only Firebase

Comment: @Fabian I have gone and updated the snippet in our repo:
https://github.com/firebase/snippets-rules

So this will get picked up as soon as we republish the docs page.  Thanks!